# How to parse JSON data properly if some data is NSNull

Tags: ios, json, swift, twitter

I'm currently pulling data via Twitter's Search API.

Once I receive the data, I am trying to parse and save the data to my TweetDetails class (which is to hold the author's name, the url of their profile pic, the text of the tweet, the location of the tweet, the tweet id and user id).

In some cases, the Tweets do not have a location (I think it has something to do if they're retweeted), and the certain dictionary (here being tweetsDict["place"]) that would otherwise hold that information, instead returns NSNull.

On those occasions, I receive this error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1093a1600) to 'NSDictionary' (0x1093a0fe8).

Here is my code as I am trying to parse the data and save it to objects in my TweetDetails class

```
    client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
        if connectionError != nil {
            print("Error: \(connectionError)")
        }
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])

            if let tweets = json["statuses"] as? [NSDictionary] {
                for tweetsDict in tweets {
                    let text = tweetsDict["text"] as! String
                    let tweetID = tweetsDict["id_str"] as! String
                    let place = tweetsDict["place"] as! NSDictionary

                    // this line ^^ is where the error occurs
                    let city = place.valueForKey("full_name")
                    let user = tweetsDict["user"] as! NSDictionary
                    let userID = user.valueForKey("id_str")
                    let screenName = user.valueForKey("screen_name")!
                    let avatarImage = user.valueForKey("profile_image_url_https")!

                    let tweet = TweetDetails(authors: screenName as! String, profileImages: avatarImage as! String, tweetTexts: text, tweetLocations: city as! String , tweetIDs: tweetID , userIDs: userID as! String)
                    self.allTweets.append(tweet)
                    self.tweetTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonError as NSError {
            print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

I have tried to create some 'if-let' statements to provide alternatives for these occasions, but nothing has worked.

Could someone please help me to create a custom alternative around when certain JSON data returns as NSNull.  (Even something as simple as turning my "city" variable into the string "Unknown Location" in the cases when the data returns NSNull).

Thanks in advance and please let me know if there is anything else I can add to provide more clarity to this question.

Comment: In short, never use forced casting of `as!` unless you know that the value can never be `nil`. Also, if there is a connection error, this code will crash (because `data` may be `nil` and you proceed to perform a forced unwrapping of it). Perhaps insert a `return` statement in that clause where you print the error message (or use `guard`), so that if there was an error, you don't proceed to perform `JSONObjectWithData` using `data!`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can use optional binding (`if let`), or, in this case, even easier, just employ optional chaining:

```
let city = tweetsDict["place"]?["full_name"] as? String
```

This way, `city` is an optional, i.e. if no value was found because there was no `place` or `full_name` entry, it will be `nil`.

It would appear, though, that your `TweetDetails` is force casting `city` to a `String`. Does it absolutely require a city? It would be best to change this method so that `city` was optional and gracefully handle `nil` values there. Alternatively, you can replace `nil` values for `city` to some other string, e.g. with the `nil` coalescing operator:

```
let city = tweetsDict["place"]?["full_name"] as? String ?? "Unknown city"
```

That returns the city if found, and "Unknown city" if not.

Comment: Thanks Rob, this definitely fixed the immediate problem.  Also, thank you @ZGski and AntoineLamy, your posts will help me on how to better set this all up in the future...

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of force data type casting in your code witch is very dangerous, especially when parsing JSON. The correct way of dealing with nullability is not to avoid it by trying to do the same thing we did in objective-c but to prepare to receive nil and react accordingly. Your data model should represent the fact that sometime a tweet have no location so some properties of TweetDetails should be marked as optionals.

The code exemple bellow is completely untested but give you an idea of what your code can look like dealing with nullability.

```
client.sendTwitterRequest(request) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
    if connectionError != nil {
        print("Error: \(connectionError)")
    }
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
    if let tweets = json["statuses"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
        for tweetsDict in tweets {
            if let text = tweetsDict["text"] as? String,
            tweetID = tweetsDict["id_str"] as? String {

                var city: String?
                if let place = tweetsDict["place"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    city = place.valueForKey("full_name")
                }

                var userID: String?
                var screenName: String?
                var avatarImage: String?
                if let user = tweetsDict["user"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    userID = user["id_str"] as? String
                    screenName = user["screen_name"] as? String
                    avatarImage = user["profile_image_url_https"] as? String
                }

                let tweet = TweetDetails(authors: screenName, profileImages: avatarImage, tweetTexts: text, tweetLocations: city, tweetIDs: tweetID, userIDs: userID)
                self.allTweets.append(tweet)
            }
        }
        self.tweetTableView.reloadData()
    }
} catch let jsonError as NSError {
    print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work because you've defined `city` inside the scope of the optional binding clause, but it's needed after that in `TweetDetails` call.

Comment: You are right @Rob, I modified my answer accordingly but the actual code here is not really important, it is more about the correct way of handling nullability. If some value can be nil, it means it should be declared as an optional in the model class instead of force unwrapping everything. In the exemple, the property `city` should be declared as: `let city: String?` in the `TweetDetails` object.